# Javascript events - inline vs .on(..), how many handlers it creates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, inline

Assuming I have this code, button with inline onclick event:

```
<button onclick='..js stuff..'>mybutton</button>
```

I have this button created multiple times because of server-side loop.

Or I would be better giving a class to these buttons, and just do (using jQuery):

```
$(".button-class").on('click',function(){..});
```

What is better in terms of performance?

My questions are-
In the inline onclick, does it creates a handler for each button?
In jQuery event binding, does the handler is created only once, and is binded for each button, or, here as well, the handler is created multiple times?

I guess that these are the factors which affect any performance difference. Perhaps the only downside for `.on(..)` is that I have to do DOM search by class name. (?)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it doesn't matter.

Use the latter (jQuery binding) because it moves the code away from the DOM and makes it easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

With the inline attribute a *different* handler is theoretically added for each event; each attribute implicitly creates a *new* callback/function<sup>1</sup> that wraps the supplied code. This handler will be *replaced* if the attribute (or corresponding DOM property) is assigned a different value later. In the case when *all* the event handlers have been created this is the "worst" approach in terms of book-keeping.

With the jQuery (addEventListener) version the *same* function callback is *added for all* the matching elements. Multiple event handlers for the same element/event may be added; care may be required to avoid unintentional repeated-binding.

Furthermore, with [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery *could* avoid binding to each element separately (ie. it only binds one event handler further up the propagation chain). Depending on how many elements are to have events "attached", this could result in a significant decrease of actual events listened to while still only using a single event handler function.

The chance of their being an *actual* real-world performance difference between the approaches is slim-to-none, degenerate cases aside. Use the form that is most clear/extensible/maintainable which, IMOHO, is rarely the event properties; especially when embedded directly into HTML attributes. (One issue with the inline attribute form is that it cannot bind to an appropriate closure context and so it must use - ick! - global context in many cases.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Browsers first *only* had inline events (almost exclusively specified in HTML attributes) and are well-optimized for this case. The actual event handler function is only created *on demand*. Consider the case of `<button onclick="alert(">Hi!</button>`, where the "onclick" contains a syntax error in the inline JavaScript. A modern browser will *only* parse the JS (and thus *only* create the actual handler function) when the the button is clicked or the `.onclick` property is read.

Comment: Your answer and answer by Zeke Sonxx does not exacly match. You're saying that only one handler is created.  I'm actually refering to mobile devices. When you say browsers are optimized to create inline events handlers on-demand, I guess it includes mobile browsers as well?  I'm trying to improve mobile performance of my JQM website

Comment: @user3599803 It is important to separate an event being bound (aka "listener") to an element and the function/handler the event is bound to - with that view the answers agree ;-) While the optimization will also apply to mobile browsers, it still doesn't make inline events any "better" in terms of a clean design. If I was wanting to optimize a page I would *first* find out if/where it was slow and only then fix it. It is fairly unlikely that a performance issue (on anything a real smart-phone and above) is related to click events. (Make a case otherwise for a *specific* site/scenario!)

Answer (score 0):

Using `onclick` is frowned upon and considered bad form, you should instead be using `element.on('click')` with jQuery or `ng-click` in Angular.js.

They both result in the same number of listeners, and basically the same performance.

Comment: Would you care to explain 3 1/2 years later why is it frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

The counter part using on.event is: if you reload Or rerender the objects using akax you need to instanciate the on.event again, it creates more code and thats more complicated.